# jQuery - Cycle Plugin Pause/Play button

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I am using the Cycle Slider plugin found at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

I've included user controls on the bottom with images ( a left arrow for Prev, right arrow for Next, and two bars for Play/Pause).
The Prev and Next buttons work perfectly. I'm stuck on the Play/Pause button though.

I don't know how to make the image change to a Play symbol when clicked and back to a Pause symbol when clicked again.

Here is the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{$('#slides').cycle({ pager: '#slideshow_links', pause: 1, speed: 1200, timeout: 6000,  next: '#next',prev: '#prev', cleartype:  true, cleartypeNoBg:  true });});</script>
```

And here's the HTML. Ideally, the Pause/Play button would go in between the two buttons there.

```
  <div id="controls">
    <span><a href="" id="prev"><img src="/images/left.gif" width="14" height="11" alt="Previous" title="Previous" style="border:0;"></a></span>
    <span><a href="" id="next"><img src="/images/right.gif" width="14" height="11" alt="Next" title="Next" style="border:0;"></a></span>
</div>
```

I already looked at the list of examples in the website, but I'm rather inexperienced in jQuery so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: updated that answer for you, lmk how it works.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Gcqfu/

```
<div id="controls">
    <span><a href="#" id="prev"><img src="/images/left.gif" width="14" height="11" alt="Previous" title="Previous" style="border:0;"></a></span>
     <span><a href="#" id="pauseOrPlay" data-playing='false'><img src="/images/play.gif" width="14" height="11" alt="Play" title="Play" style="border:0;"></a></span>
    <span><a href="#" id="next"><img src="/images/right.gif" width="14" height="11" alt="Next" title="Next" style="border:0;"></a></span>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#pauseOrPlay").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this),
        playing = $this.data("playing"),
        $slides = $("#slides");
   if (!playing)
   {
       $this.data("playing", true);
       $this.children("img:first").attr("src", "/images/pause.gif").attr("title", "Pause").attr("alt", "Pause");  
       // call play for the plugin here
       $slides.cycle('resume');
   } 
    else
    {
        $this.data("playing", false);
       $this.children("img:first").attr("src", "/images/play.gif").attr("title", "Play").attr("alt", "Play");  
       // call pause for the plugin here 
       $slides.cycle('pause');
    }    
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. The button works perfectly. However, it has no effect on the slider. Maybe because it is set to autoplay? Either way, the slider never stops no matter how many times you try to pause. Previously, I used one of the default options the plugin provided called "toggle" which alternates between play and pause on click. But it doesn't change the image, so I didn't go with it.

Comment: I've never used or looked at the plugin. I'm assuming you'd have to add some more logic to actually use the plugin, this just toggles the image and gives you a place to call play or pause..

Comment: `$('#slides').cycle('pause');` and `$('#slides').cycle('resume');` is what you'll want to pause and play it.